# iMessage bubble in iOS 7

Tags: ios, crop, ios7, imessage

In iOS7 there is significant cropping (40-50%)– of MMS/GIF messages and photos (new “Square” orientation)  - within the iMessage chat bubble. This was not a problem in ios6  - for MMS/animated gif/video files.

In iOS6-we could control the visibility of the MMS/GIF to perfectly “fit ” the chat bubble, by reducing the resolution of the MMS/GIF. However – reducing the resolution of the MMS/GIF files in iOS7 does not change the proportion of the message visible in the chat window.

Any body have any temporary  “work around” solutions for this bug – or have any ideas on how we can present an animated GIF/MMS without significant cropping in the iMessage chat bubble?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Even though iOS 7 in now a GM version, I would recommend asking this question in the Apple Development Forums.  It may even be a bug in iOS 7.

Comment: Did you find a solution?